# Data Migrating document for Couchbase (i.e changing existing field type)?

Tags: couchbase, nosql

I am coming from object relation database background, I understand Couchbase is schema-less, but data migration will still happen as the application develop.

In SQL we have management tool to alter table, or I can write migration script with SQL to do migration from version 1 table to version 2 table.

But in document, say we have json Document UserProfile:

```
UserProfile
{
  "Owner": "Rich guy!",
  "Car": "Cool car"
}
```

We might want to add a last visit field there, allow user have multiple car, so the new updated document will become follows:

```
UserProfile
{
  "Owner": "Rich guy!",
  "Car": ["Cool car", "Another car"],
  "LastVisit": "2015-09-29"
}
```

But for easier maintenance, I want all other UserProfile documents to follow the same format, having "Car" field as an array.

From my experience in SQL, I could write migration script which support migrating different version of table.  Migrate from version 1 table to version 2...N table.

So how can I should I write such migration code?  I will have to really just writing an app (executable) using Couchbase SDK to migrate all the documents each time?

What will be the good way for doing migration like this?

Comment: I've read your question a few times and I still dont understand what you're asking here. Perhaps you could rephrase? Keep in mind that CB doesn't care about your class modeling: its simply a place you store docs. Docs can be added, removed and modified.

In my experience things get a lot more interesting when you need to retrieve groups of docs and iterate them (using views, for example). You should definitely incorporate those considerations into your modeling.

Comment: While not exactly an answer to your question, which is why I put it as a comment, I'd recommend you read this blog post as it will give you some ideas about object modeling in Couchbase, what is possible and why you may or may not do something. http://blog.couchbase.com/user-profile-store-advanced-data-modeling

Comment: @FuzzyAmi I do understand CB doesn't care about my class modeling and is a simply a place to store docs.  But at the end I will have to map the docs from CB to my app data model.  If my app data model changed/extended, need to store more information i.e Store not single car information, but multiple cars.  In that case I need to update the every CB docs in order to store multiple cars information, by changing doc's car field into array.  What I meant is data migration, like from a SQL table with a column string type, and we want to change the column to int type etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any official tool currently to help with data model migrations, but there are some helpful code snippets depending on the SDK you use (see e.g. [bulk updates](https://gist.github.com/daschl/4ce7a375a3aefd170b50) in java).

For now you will have to write your own script. The basic process is as follow:

- Make sure all your documents have a `model_version` attribute that you increment after each migration.
- Before a migration update your application code so it can handle both the old and the new `model_version`, and so that new documents are written in the new model.
- Write a script that iterate through all the old model documents in your bucket(you need a view that emits the document key), make the update you want, increment `model_version` and save the document back.

In a high concurrency environment it's important to have good error handling and monitoring, you could have for example a view that counts how many documents are in each `model_version`.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, your problem breaks down into two parts:

1. Finding all the documents that need to be updated.
2. Retrieving and updating said documents.

You can do this in one of two ways: using a view that gives you the document ids, or using a DCP stream to get all the documents from the bucket. The view only gives you the ids of the documents, so you basically iterate over all the ids, and then retrieve, update and store each one using regular key-value methods. The DCP protocol, on the other hand, gives you the actual documents.

The advantage of using a view is that it's very simple to implement, works with any language SDK, and it lets you write your own logic around the process to make it more robust and safe. The disadvantage is having to build a view just for this, and also that if the data keeps changing, you must retrieve the ENTIRE view result at once, because if you try to page over the view with offsets, the ordering of results can change, thus giving you an inconsistent snapshot of the data.

The advantage of using DCP to stream all documents is that you're guaranteed to get a consistent snapshot of your data even if it's constantly changing, and also that you get the whole document directly as part of the stream, so you don't need to retrieve it separately - just update and store back to the database. The disadvantage is that it's currently only implemented in the Java SDK and is considered an experimental feature. See [this blog](http://nosqlgeek.blogspot.co.il/2015/05/dcp-magic.html) for a simple implementation.

The third - and most convenient for an SQL user - way to do this is through the N1QL query language that's introduced in [Couchbase 4](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/downloads#Couchbase_Server). It has the same [data manipulation commands](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/update.html) as you would expect in SQL, so you could basically issue a command along the lines of `UPDATE myBucket SET prop = {'field': 'value'} WHERE condition = 'something'`. The advantage of this is pretty clear: it both finds and updates the documents all at once, without writing a single line of program code. The disadvantage is that the DML commands are considered "beta" in the 4.0 release of Couchbase, and that if the data set is too large, then it might not actually work due to timing out at some point. And of course, that fact that you need Couchbase 4.0 in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Couchmove](https://github.com/differentway/couchmove), which is a java migration tool working like Flyway DB.

You can execute N1QL queries with this tool to migrate your documents and keep tracking of your changes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the crux here is getting and then 'update every CB docs'. This can be done with a view, provided that you understand that views are only 'eventually consistent' (unlike read/write actions which are strongly consistent).

If (at migration-time) no new documents are added to your bucket, then your view would be up-to-date and should return the entire set of documents to be migrated. easy.

On the other hand, if new documents continue to be written into your bucket, and these documents need to be migrated, then you will have to run your migration code continually to catch all these new docs (since the view wont return them until it is updated, a few seconds later).

In this 2nd scenario, while migration is happening, your bucket will contain a heterogeneous collection of docs: some that have been migrated already, some that are about to be migrated and some that your view has not 'seen' yet (because they were recently added) and would only be migrated once you re-run the migration code.

To make the migration process efficient, you'll need to find a way to differentiate between already-migrated items and yet-to-be-migrated items. You can add a field to each doc with its 'version number' and update it during the migration. Your view should be defined to only select documents with older 'version number' and ignore already-migrated items.

I suggest you read more about couchbase views - here and on their site.

Regarding your migration: There are two aspects here: (1) getting the list of document ids that need to be updated and (2) the actual update.

The actual update is simple: you retrieve the doc and save it again with the new format. There's no explicit schema. Where once you added column in SQL and populated it, you now just add a field in the json-doc (of all the docs). All migrated docs should have this field. Side note: Things get little more complicated if (while you're migrating) the document can be updated by another process. This requires special handling (read aboud CAS if that's the case).

Getting all the relevant doc-keys requires that you define a view and query it. Its beyond the scope of this answer (and is very well documented). Once you have all the keys, you simply iterate them one by one and update them.

Comment: If I understood correctly, too? Yes, there would be case if new documents continue to be written into bucket, I will need to somehow distinguish between before migration data and migrated data using flag or version number as you suggested.  I will probably  do it in easy way, pull down server for data migration.  But my question is more like about, how I should write the migration code to migrate the data (document).  Is not like SQL have management tool, or I can write a migration script with SQL to alter table, change type etc.

Comment: Sorry, seems like my question is too confusing, I rewrote my question. :(

Comment: I added more details. I guess i'm still not sure what exactly you're not clear about. Is thera a specific programming language you wish to use?

Comment: I just not sure how should I migrate the data, is there tool? or basically I just have to write code? If the only way is to pull down the document and resave the update the format for each.  Then in order for me to support migrating different version of document to latest, I will have to write method for each version: MigrateVersion1To2 method, MigrateVersion2To3 method, MigrateVersion3To4 method etc?  The migration method will basically pull the document, map to different version data object class, resave with new version data object...?

Comment: :] You'll need to write code. I'm not familiar with any transformation/migration tools for couch. Perhaps you should post another question explicitly asking whether a migration tool (that can transform docs) exists. (a tool that migrates from one bucket to another exists - cbtransfer - , but you want to transform the docs as well)

Answer (score 0):

With N1QL, Couchbase provides the same schema migration capabilities as you have in RDBMS or object-relational database. For the example in your question, you can place the following query in a migration script:

```
UPDATE UserProfile
SET Car = TO_ARRAY(Car),
LastVisit = NOW_STR();
```

This will migrate all the documents in your bucket to your new schema. Note that update statements in Couchbase provide document-level atomicity, not statement-level atomicity. But since this update is idempotent (repeatable), you can run it multiple times if you run into errors. Note: similar to the last paragraph of David's answer above.